# caldigit ts3 plus dual monitor on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and Thinkpad T14

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, thunderbolt

I am getting only one monitor via my caldigit ts3 plus dock (and charging as well); The dock is connected to the Thunderbolt 3 connection on the laptop. The dock working perfectly on a Macbook Pro that I have as well.

Any thoughts on how to get both screens shown will be welcome.

Comment: Any luck? I am also having problems with the same setup on Thinkpad P1.

Comment: Nop, I assume it's because the TB3 only supports 2 lanes and not 4 lanes - meaning only one screen. I'm currently using the HDMI to connect my second screen...

Comment: I've just ran the Ubuntu update, and now it works after restart. I see both monitors, plus laptop as a 3rd screen, all part of an extended desktop.

Comment: @Danijel which update? 20.10 beta?

Comment: No, just a few packages were updated... and I switched the graphics driver to NVidia, maybe that was important.

Comment: My build does not have the NVidia card only the basic Intel card...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Thinkpad T14 uses the 15BF Thunderbolt Controller / [Intel JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Controller](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/94030/intel-jhl6240-thunderbolt-3-controller.html). It only supports 2 lanes instead of 4 lanes that are needed to control two external screens.

The weird thing: If you try another dock like the Lenovo Dock Gen 2 it will work with two external monitors. I think Lenovo uses some special techniques like Multi Stream Tansport (MST), Displaylink etc.

But if you are now considering switching to the official Lenovo dock, please wait, because two external monitors in extended mode won't work with your MacBook Pro as shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/SpjYKy3AiW4).

To solve the problem, I suggest buying an HDMI/DP to USB-C adapter. Now you have got two cables:

- Cable 1: Connected to the CalDigit TS3+ where your first monitor and all your devices (mouse, keyboard) are attached
- Cable 2: The USB-C to HDMI/DP Adapter connected to your second monitor

With this setup you can't make your one-cable-dream come true, but you are able to use the CalDigit TS3+ dock on your MacBook Pro and Lenovo Thinkpad T14 with two external monitors.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it it this or not, but I had some issues with the dock when connecting to Ubuntu and didn't realise you had to 'authorize' the new thunderbolt device in settings. Just in case anyone is as daft as me....

Comment: Same thing on a T490s running 20.04.3